# PDO with MSSQL driver how to get output parameters?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, freetds

When you are using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) with [MSSQL driver](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) you actually use [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) as low level driver. There is some different ways to execute stored procedures - **language queries** and [**RPC call**](http://www.freetds.org/tds.html).

FreeTDS also supports TDS protocol version 4.2 and 7.x. The one of main difference between them is a behaviour of stored procedure call. Microsoft changed the behaviour from protocol 4.2 to 7.0
not returning output parameters from language queries. **Language queries** mainly send the textual query to the server wrapping into a TDS packet.

#### Example of language query with PDO (from [php.net](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements))

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_takes_string_returns_string(?)");
    $value = 'Hello!';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 
    $stmt->execute();
    print "The output is $value\n";
```

Actually you send something like "EXEC sp_takes....". And if you run sample above with MSSQL you would get empty output parameter in TDS 7.х and expected result with 4.2. Why we can`t use 4.2 and be happy? It has a lot of [limitations](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm):

- ASCII only, of course.
- RPC and BCP is not supported.
- varchar fields are limited to 255 characters. If your table defines longer fields, they'll be truncated.
- dynamic queries (also called `prepared statements`) are not supported.

So, the 4.2 is not a variant.

#### Example of RPC call (from [php.net odbtp extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php))

```
    $stmt = mssql_init('sp_takes_string_returns_string');
    $value = 'Hello!';
    mssql_bind($stmt, 1, $value, SQLVARCHAR, true,  false,   4000);
    mssql_execute($stmt);
    print "The output is $value\n";
```

Using sample above with native mssql extension in php you got right result with TDS 7.2. Actually you send binary RPC packet with that code.

### Question

Is there is any way to make RPC call for stored procedure with PDO and MSSQL driver?

Comment: I remember something about needing to consume the result-set for the outputs to be assigned.  Have you tried calling to $stmt->fetchAll(); after your call to execute : `mssql_execute($stmt); $stmt->fetchAll(); ...` , but before using the value of $value.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately.

Comment: I've found the right syntax. See my answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224294/2717254

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling stored procedure with Out parameter using PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382922/calling-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter-using-pdo)

Answer (score 2):

Either I missed FreeTDS when I first answered, or this question was updated.
Either way...

FreeTDS Does not support output parameters in MSSQL Server 7 SP3 or greater. This is due to changes made in SQL Server.

---Old Response Below---

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for.
I ran through some old files to the only time I'd linked to MSSQL and pulled this.

```
$con = mssql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
mssql_select_db($db['database'], $con);//Select DB
$result = mssql_query("my_Procedure_Name ".$propertyOne.", ".$propertyTwo."");
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
 try {
    $hostname = "myhost";
    $port = 10060;
    $dbname = "tempdb";
    $username = "dbuser";
    $pw = "password";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select name from master..sysdatabases where name = db_name()");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

Comment: This is not in any way relevant to the question.