# Create field from auto increment value on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to `INSERT` a row into a table which contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, and use the resulting `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to construct another field in the same row, in a single query?

I know it can be done in two operations.

Our product uses a 16 character numeric account ID stored as `CHAR(16)`. We like to store the account ID as a single field as it is referenced in many tables throughout our database(s), however it is made up of the following parts:

```
AccountType INT(4) UNSIGNED // never less than 1000
AccountNumber INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
AccountSite INT(2) UNSIGNED
```

Which are concatenated in order to produce the 16 character accountID field. The AccountType value is never less than 1000.

I would like to be able to perform a single `INSERT` operation that produces the four fields within the same query, if possible.

Comment: you can call a stored proc with the 4 parameters, or use an `after` trigger (I don't do a lot of triggers, I guess the id is avail)

Comment: This could be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column If you have 5.7, check the newer answers

Comment: @Terminus I don't think so :p

Comment: @Drew edited comment cause words are hard and I'm tired

Comment: The problem is that if he wants it as an FK it can't be used. But I know what ya mean.

Comment: He would certainly like to use it as a FK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show this with a stored procedure. You may in the end only want 1 or 2 columns in the table. But I am showing more (assuming a text user friendly string too). That part is trivial, to shrink it down in column count.

**Schema:**

```
drop table if exists tX4;
create table tX4
(   AccountType INT(4) UNSIGNED not null, -- // never less than 1000
    AccountNumber INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    AccountSite INT(2) UNSIGNED not null,
    col4 varchar(50) not null,
    weWantThis char(16) not null
);
-- truncate tX4; -- used for testing
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ins_tX4;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_tX4
(    p_AccountType int,
     p_AccountSite int,
     p_col4 varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE theAI int;
    DECLARE sConcatFix char(16);

    START TRANSACTION;
    insert tX4(AccountType,AccountSite,col4,weWantThis) values (p_AccountType,p_AccountSite,p_col4,'');
    set theAI=last_insert_id();
    set sConcatFix=concat( lpad(p_AccountType,4,'0'), lpad(theAi,10,'0'),  lpad(p_AccountSite,2,'0')  );
    update tX4 set weWantThis=sConcatFix where AccountNumber=theAI;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
call ins_tX4(1,2,'cat');

select * from tX4;
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------+------------------+
| AccountType | AccountNumber | AccountSite | col4 | weWantThis       |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------+------------------+
|           1 |             1 |           2 | cat  | 0001000000000102 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+------+------------------+
```

Visualized pieces:

```
0001 0000000001 02
```

Which is AccountType, the AI, AccountSite (widths 4,10,2) respectively.

```
call ins_tX4(8765,42,'Sunday');

select * from tX4;
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
| AccountType | AccountNumber | AccountSite | col4   | weWantThis       |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
|           1 |             1 |           2 | cat    | 0001000000000102 |
|        8765 |             2 |          42 | Sunday | 8765000000000242 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
```

Column `weWantThis` could be used as the target for an FK from other tables.

Manual page for [`LPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) (Left Padding).

### **Edit**

With an `OUT` parameter to send back the AI # assigned. Note that parameters are `IN` parameters by default.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ins_tX4;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_tX4
(   p_AccountType int,
    p_AccountSite int,
    p_col4 varchar(50),
    OUT AI_assigned int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE theAI int;
    DECLARE sConcatFix char(16);

    -- AI means database-assigned AUTO INCREMENT
    set AI_assigned = -1; -- assume an Error condition
    START TRANSACTION;
        insert tX4(AccountType,AccountSite,col4,weWantThis) values (p_AccountType,p_AccountSite,p_col4,'');
        set theAI=last_insert_id();
        set sConcatFix=concat( lpad(p_AccountType,4,'0'), lpad(theAi,10,'0'),  lpad(p_AccountSite,2,'0')  );
        update tX4 set weWantThis=sConcatFix where AccountNumber=theAI;
        set AI_assigned = theAI; -- the OUT parameter is set to the AI value
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test from mysql environment:**

```
set @var1 = -1;

call ins_tX4(22,33,'Monday',@var1);
select @var1;
-- 3

call ins_tX4(333,79,'Tuesday',@var1);
select @var1;
-- 4
```

**Test from a PHP environment:**

Because this question is tagged `PHP`, see an answer like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432579) from user Matteo Tassinari.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. What made you declare`sConcatFix` as `varchar(20)` instead of `varchar(16)` or `char(16)`?

Comment: Years of `c` programming and paranoia. 16 is fine. It is just a local var to the proc anyway, not in the table. Yes, char(16) is fine for the table.

Comment: I think it was the decade of programming in ms sql-server and the fixed space left debris that one would have to clean or trim. So everything is varchar's these days. But yes, yours is a char(16). Sorry about that confusion

Comment: Can this be accomplished using a transaction? Take a look at the answer I've added.

Comment: My code shows a transaction (not sure what you mean)

Comment: Sorry - not clear.  I mean using a transaction written as a single query.

Comment: I resolved this for you with a stored proc wrapper. It is pretty simple. A single call to the stored proc. Otherwise, look at all of the answers to this question ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2708237

Comment: You're right, looks like it's essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a `TRANSACTION`.

```
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO accounts (accountType, accountSite) VALUES(1000,10); 
UPDATE accounts SET accountID = CONCAT(LPAD(accountType, 4, '0'), LPAD(accountNumber, 10, '0'), LPAD(accountSite, 2, '0')) WHERE accountNumber = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
COMMIT;
```

Which could for example be executed in php as:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts (accountType, accountSite) VALUES(1000,10);"
$query .= "UPDATE accounts SET accountID = CONCAT(LPAD(accountType, 4, '0'), LPAD(accountNumber, 10, '0'), LPAD(accountSite, 2, '0')) WHERE accountNumber = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
$mysqli->query($query);
$mysqli->commit();
```