# Calling stored procedure from PHP using PDO to MSSQL Server using INPUT Paramters

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, fetch, sqlsrv

This does not work:

```
  $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=xxxx;dbname=xxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("{exec wcweb_UserInfo(?)}");
  $sth->bindParam(1, $name);
  $sth->execute();

  while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($result);
  }
```

This also does not work:

```
  $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=xxxxx;dbname=xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx");

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("{call wcweb_UserInfo(?)}");
  $sth->bindParam(1, $name);
  $sth->execute();

  while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($result);
  }
```

This DOES work:

```
  $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=xxxxx;dbname=xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx");

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("exec wcweb_UserInfo @userid=?");
  $sth->bindParam(1, $name);
  $sth->execute();

  while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($result);
  }
```

I tried the above using 2 that did not work with and without the curly brackets, etc.  I know some would say, well just do it the way it works?  .. The problem is I am porting an exising application from an IIS Server using the sqlsrv_query library to a Linux server.

All of the database calls in the app are written in functions that use this method: {call wcweb_UserInfo(?)}  .. None of the parameter names are specified, so I would have to modify every database call to include the parameter names.  I was under the impression that the PDO library for PHP5 can do those same kind of calls?

Help!  Is there something I am doing wrong or is it just that PDO can't make those kinds of calls?

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: No error messages at all.. thats the weird thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason this works:

```
  $sth = $dbh->prepare("exec wcweb_UserInfo ?");
  $sth->bindParam(1, $name);
  $sth->execute();

  while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($result);
  }
```

I might be able to live with this.  Anyone know why the other methods do not work?  Is it a difference in the libraries?

Comment: Sorry, before I missed the fact that that you were using SQL Server. SQL Server doesn't use parentheses for stored procedure calls.