# PHP call to SQL server stored procedure doesn't work when ported from Windows to Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo

This is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466503/calling-stored-procedure-from-php-using-pdo-to-mssql-server-using-input-paramter), but I need to capture output.  It seems to be basically an issue with getting the correct syntax, but using the syntax suggested in the answer didn't work for me.

I have a php application that calls a stored procedure on a SQL Server database which I developed on my Windows laptop running xampp.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[check_for_barcode] @Sample_Id nvarchar(20), @Barcode_In_table int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT @Barcode_In_table = count(*) FROM dbo.sample_info
WHERE sample_name = @Sample_Id

RETURN @Barcode_In_table

GO
```

The php code that works on Windows xampp looks like this:

```
// use a sample Id known to be present in database
$sample_yes = '11335577';
// use a sample Id known NOT to be in database
$sample_no = '0011223344';

$host = 'hostIP';
$db = 'db';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pw';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$db", $user, $password);
    $sql = "{CALL dbo.check_for_barcode(@Sample_Id=:barcode, @Barcode_In_table=:isInDatabase)}";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt-> bindParam('barcode', $sample_yes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('isInDatabase', $isInDatabase, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'for sample id 11335577 $isInDatabase = '.$isInDatabase."\n";

    $stmt-> bindParam(':barcode', $sample_no);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'for sample id 0011223344 $isInDatabase = '.$isInDatabase;

    $stmt->closeCursor();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The output is:
for sample id 11335577 $isInDatabase = 1
for sample id 0011223344 $isInDatabase = 0

Since moving it to the Linux (Ubuntu 4.24) server where it will be deployed, it no longer works.

I installed the dblib drivers as described [here](http://grover.open2space.com/content/use-php-and-pdo-connect-ms-sql-server).

I adapted the code to as required to use the dblib driver so that it would run without errors.  This only involved changing the first two lines inside the try statement.

I have changed the first line to:

```
...
 $conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
...
```

I have tried all of the following for the second line:

```
$sql = "{CALL dbo.check_for_barcode(@Sample_Id=:barcode, @Barcode_In_table=:isInDatabase)}";
$sql = "{CALL dbo.check_for_barcode @Sample_Id=:barcode, @Barcode_In_table=:isInDatabase}";
$sql = "CALL dbo.check_for_barcode(@Sample_Id=:barcode, @Barcode_In_table=:isInDatabase)";
$sql = "CALL dbo.check_for_barcode :barcode, :isInDatabase";
```

As well as all of the above using EXEC instead of CALL

The output in all cases is:
for sample id 11335577 $isInDatabase = 
for sample id 0011223344 $isInDatabase =

If I add ...

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
  var_dump($result);
}
```

... this generates no output.
 There are no error message at all, so I can't see where the problem is.  I would welcome any suggestions on what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I had to do this, but I used ODBC to connect to SQL Server from PHP running on a linux box.

Drivers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ff657782.aspx

ODBC docs - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php

EDIT: The ODBC drivers above are for Windows, the Linux installation instructions and drivers can be found at www.php.net/pdo_odbc

Comment: Thanks @hellsgate, but these links are for drivers for a Windows box

Comment: Sorry about that, you can get the linux drivers from www.php.net/pdo_odbc