# How to Exec Procedure SQL Server on Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have a trouble, when to execute procedure SQL Server on laravel.

The error

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. (SQL: EXEC pr_stop 14)

And my sript

```
    public function stopLine(Request $request){

    $stop = Engine::where([['code', $request->engine]])
                          ->first();

      $quest = [$stop->id];

      DB::connection('mssql')->select('EXEC pr_stop ?', $quest);

    return $this->sendResponse($stop, 'Data successfully');
  }
```

How to fix them, because i stuck on this on using array / string data to parameter

Comment: It's not db::connection-> select, but you have to do something else. Try something like `query` first, but also check PDO's documentation. DB:: is basically PDO. Before you do, also check that Stored Procedure itself, because of the error message

Comment: What's the proc do?

Comment: To stop automation counting data input @Xedni

Comment: I'm check manually exec in sql server management its safe, but when im go to laravel i get the error. Can you explaine with example pleasee @UnderDog

Comment: Does the proc return results? The error makes me think it's  expecting a result set and the proc isn't returning one

Comment: I can't explain much, but check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466870/1294911 I know a SP as just a select statement, for example: `select * from users where id = ?`, then I execute my SP (see link) and that gives me the result. Example = PDO. PDO = Laravel's DB class, same functions

Comment: Return result but with no columns name, i just give a name on columns(field) ? @Xedni

Comment: Okay i will check @UnderDog

Comment: Is the stored proc doing any `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operations before it gets around to doing the `SELECT`? These operations will be generating rowcount events that could be tripping up Laravel, so try using `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of the stored proc's code.

Comment: Yes true, i just give a name on the column thankssssss :DD @Xedni

Comment: or using another way with using SET NOCOUNT ON thanks too @AlwaysLearning :D